# How to access serer on windows machine by name with non-windows machine?

Tags: c#, android, windows-networking

I have built a small server application using c#.

The idea is that people on the LAN will be able to access the server by machine name (the name of the machine hosting the server) as well as IP address.

This works fine when I use another windows machine. However, when I use the Google Browser on an Android, only the IP works.

Is there some way I can configure the host machine to ensure non-windows machines can use the machine name?

Answer (score 0):

On an Ethernet network, when using TCP/IP, hosts communicate with one another by IP address.  Even when you specify a host by name, it's IP address is used in communication.

This is done by a service that should be available on your network that is known as Domain Name Services (DNS).  The IP stack on the source host that is attempting to communicate to the target host by name uses DNS to resolve the target host's name to its IP address.

You can determine if DNS is working by using a NSLOOKUP utility on the host that is having problems reaching the target host.  If NSLOOKUP is failing, there may be a DNS issue that needs to be resolved.

Before troubleshooting your custom application, ensure that the host that's trying to communicate with the target host can indeed do so via simple TCP/IP utilities.

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand what you are saying here. However, as stated above, if I connect using a remote Windows machine, it can connect using the the name of the machine hosting the server. ex; host machine is named 'ted'. I can connect with a remote Windows machine by using "http://ted", no problem. But this does not work with a non-Windows machine.

Comment: Have you tried to debug this problem using standard networking utilities?

Comment: No. I would not even know where to start there. The remote is an Android device, the target is a Windows machine. Any suggestions?

Comment: Googling "android ping nslookup" turned up this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.quirijngrootbluemink.iptools&hl=en which looks legitimate.  Once you get it, use ping to ensure you have connectivity between the machines.  You can use NSLookup to see if "ted" can be found by the Android device.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried it. It will not allow me to use the name, only an IP address or domain name.

Comment: Try to determine how your Windows hosts are resolving host names by following these instructions: http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/display/istcontrib/How+to+check+DNS+settings+on+Windows+7 Once you have that information, compare it to the DNS settings in your Android.  (Instructions can be found by Googling "android check dns settings")  Are they the same? Different?